# Laravel 5 get command response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I think I understand the concept of command in Laravel, in that it's a good place to put reuseable code, that can be called from controllers and the like, but I have a query:

Can I return a value back to the calling method from a command? For example, I have a controller method which creates a user in Active Directory, for which there is a command to do this. If the AD server is unreachable, I want to return a response back to the calling controller method. Is this possible?

[It only shows in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#dispatching-commands) how to call a command using `dispatch()`, but nothing as to whether it can return anything.

And if you cannot return a value, can someone explain the reasoning behind why you wouldn't want to return a value? I know that queued commands may take a while and wouldn't be appropriate to wait for a response, but for commands that should be executed immediately I don't see why you wouldn't want to return a value.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Commands are not for storing reusable code in controllers. Theyre getting renamed to jobs in 5.1 and their main purpose it to work as Cron Jobs. If you have a method to create a user and want to use it in many places, you could store it in the User model.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense (thinking of them as designed for Cron jobs). Thanks for clearing up my confusion, if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I think there is a little confusion about the term 'command'. Phil is referring to the command bus and you are referring to Artisan commands. Different context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the context of the command bus, yes you can return values on non-queued commands. In your command handler method, simply return what you want:

```
public function handle(){
    return 'foobar';
}
```

And save the result of your dispatch command to a variable:

```
 $my_command_result = $this->dispatch(
    new MyCommand();
);
```

Comment: I'll give it a quick go and see what happens :)

Comment: I've just tested it and is working perfectly, thanks, It does make sense, I think I'm overthinking a lot of Laravel!

Answer (score 1):

Commands are not for storing reusable code in controllers. Theyre getting renamed to jobs in [5.1](https://laravel-news.com/2015/04/laravel-5-1/) and their main purpose it to work as Cron Jobs. If you have a method to create a user and want to use it in many places, you could store it in the User model.

Comment: Creating users is not always the job of the model. Depending on the complexity of your app, you may want to use a *factory*. If you want to send a verification email, do any bootstrapping needed for new accounts, etc, then the Command bus would be a good place to create users.

Comment: @pstephan1187 is right, I misunderstood the question and his answer fits it better,  you should probably follow his advice.